# Text book for 2nd Linear Algebra course

Tags: linear-algebra

I stumbled across this site while searching for Hoffman and Kunze. There was a discussion about using HK for a beginning linear algebra course. I am teaching (for the first time) a 2nd course in linear algebra. The students will have had a beginning course in linear algebra and a beginning course in abstract algebra. I am considering HK (which I had in an undergraduate course) or Curtis.  Would you please tell me about your experiences with this course and/or these books or others? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about that site. I'll ask it there.

Comment: It will be simpler just to migrate it. I'll do that.

Comment: I closed the migrated question as the reasking *and* migration seems to be based on a misunderstanding.